# JSONify a model in Persistent *including* the id

Tags: haskell

Here's a model I have in [Persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent):

```
Tip
    text Text
    created_at UTCTime
    updated_at UTCTime
    title Text
    category_id CategoryId
```

And the related `ToJSON` instance (I couldn't use `deriveJSON`):

```
instance ToJSON Tip where
    toJSON (Tip text created_at updated_at title category_id) = object ["text" .= text, "created_at" .= created_at, "updated_at" .= updated_at, "title" .= title, "category_id" .= category_id]
```

This is almost correct except I want to JSONify the Tip's id in here too...but it's not anywhere on the model! How would I do this? Is there any way to go from an `EntityVal` to a `EntityKey`?

Comment: To get JSON deriving, just add the word `json` after `Tip`. See: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax#json-instances

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But it still doesn't include the id.

Comment: Ben's answer addresses that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Entity` is the pairing of a key and a value. If you just have the value, there's no generic way to know what id it has. If it has any unique constraints you could use that to look up the key.

A given `EntityVal` could theoretically have been assigned different ids in different backend databases (which might not even all have the same type). Or it could have been manually constructed to be inserted but hasn't actually been inserted yet, so it hasn't been assigned an id. A `Tip` value doesn't innately *have* an id; it only maybe has an id in a particular database.

Comment: Technically, this is the correct answer, and the same conclusion I came to. So my follow-up question is: why is this so hard to do? I expect a database entry to include every field, *especially* the ID. When I'm writing an app for the web, I use IDs everywhere. This seems like an unnecessary stumbling block that Persistent has added.

Comment: @VladtheImpala Well, it's necessary if you want to be able to represent `Tip` objects that don't exist in the database (say, if they come in a form from the user). You'd need either (1) separate data types for "object" and "object with id", or (2) for the id field to always be a Maybe type. Persistent's `Entity entityKey entityVal` type is basically option (1). Is it possible for you to just represent the `Entity` values instead of the `EntityVal` ones?

Comment: yeah, I see that now. Makes sense.